# Via ferratas in Pyrenees

Tags: europe, hiking, destinations, mountain-climbing, climbing

I'm looking for [via ferratas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_ferrata) somewhere in Europe, but not in the Alps or Dolomites due to financial reasons. What places do you recommend for beginner in this way of hiking?

Edit: After some research I can clarify my question: What place in Pyrennes would you recommend for via-ferrata beginner? I'm planning to stay in one place without car and make one day trips, so routes should be close to that destination.

Comment: I don't know how common via ferratas are but I do know Europe is very big. As per the Stack Exchange guidelines you can see in the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) we're not supposed to encourage list questions or subjective questions such as recommendations. If you can make your requirements a lot more specific it can narrow down the possible answers though and become quite a good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Andorra has a lot of via ferratas and is small enough to do without a car. You can find a list of all [via ferratas in Andorra](http://www.hola-andorra.com/arinsal/english/viaferratagb.html) with their corresponding difficulty level. Also you can find information about how to move through Andorra by [public transport here](http://www.transportpublic.ad/Angles/index.htm).

[image: This is the "Canal del Grau" via ferrata, a difficult one]